# Output when we check any Set!=null

Tags: java, hashset

Consider the following piece of code

```
Set<String> a = new HashSet<String>();
System.out.println(a!= null);
```

The output is true.

Please tell me what does any `Set!= null` actually checks as the desired output should have been false
P.S. - I know we can use `isEmpty()`, but i would like to know what effect does null check has

Comment: `a!=null` is always `true` because one line before, you **constructed** a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

You have actually done the instantiation and *reference* to a new `HashSet` Object for variable `a`

```
Set<String> a = new HashSet<String>();
```

so, checking it if it refers to something will return *true* only since it is not *null*

```
System.out.println(a!= null);
```

You shouldn't have instatiated your variable `a` if you want to make the test *fail* (false) by just 
doing the declaration without initialization

```
Set<String> a; // implicitly this will not refer any object. so, null
or
Set<String> a = null;
```

If you do the test,

```
 System.out.println(a!= null);
```

the result would be *false*. Adding to that, `isEmpty()` method returns true if this set contains no elements. You can make use of it when you want to check if the set is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please tell me what does any Set!= null actually checks?
```

`a!= null` checks only if the reference `a` points to Set Object(Or Polymorphic reference) or not.

This expression is usually used for NPE checks and not to check of Collection has elements or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> a = new HashSet<String>(); // here a has initialized
```

And now `a` is an empty `HashSet`.

```
Set<String> a; // now a is null since a is not initialize
```

Consider the following case

```
static Set<String> set;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(set!=null);
}
```

Now `set` is `null` and will get out put `false`

So it means `set!= null` is used to check whether `set` initialized or not for avoid occur `NullPointerException`. That is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A null check for reference is check if any object is assigned to it or not.
Here in your case reference a is already refer to HashSet Object in heap memory so it will return false.